# Can ImageFeatureTrack be used to track the IntensityCentroid of objects

Tags: image-processing

I would lik to track the `IntensityCentroid` of objects in sequentiell images by using `ImageFeatureTrack`.

A set of 100 images (png, 8bit gray scale, each image contains 3 bright objects of interest) is available here: http://preview.tinyurl.com/z8b9u8v

For illustration: first image (50% reduced size):

[image]

For illustration: all images superposed (50% reduced size):

[image]

What I did:

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir],"Directory"],Dynamic[imageDir]}];

SetDirectory[imageDir];

fNames=FileNames["*.png"];

numFiles=Length[fNames];

images = Table[Import[fNames[[i]]], {i,1,numFiles}];

{w, h} = ImageDimensions[images[[1]]];

res = ImageFeatureTrack[images];

ListLinePlot[# &@Transpose[res], PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

The objects are tracked correctly:

[image]

But the found coordinates do not correspond to the `IntensityCentroid`, nor `Centroid` or `Medoid`.

For the first 2 images I get:

```
res[[1 ;; 2, All, All]]

{{{36.5, 637.5}, {372.5, 30.5}, {733.5, 633.5}}, {{36.7581, 
   638.58}, {372.498, 32.5795}, {732.013, 631.847}}}
```

Compared to that I get with `ComponentMeasurements` different coordinates:

```
(* first image *)

image = images[[1]];

t = FindThreshold[image, Method -> "Entropy"];

binImage = Binarize[image, t];
binImage2 = DeleteSmallComponents[binImage, 8];

newImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage2];

ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]]

{{40.0884, 637.066}, {731.587, 633.121}, {374.29, 29.9678}}

ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "Centroid"][[All, 2]]

{{40.1854, 636.86}, {731.5, 632.77}, {374.088, 29.9706}}

ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "Medoid"][[All, 2]]

{{40.5, 636.5}, {731.5, 632.5}, {374.5, 29.5}}

(* second image *)

image = images[[2]];

t = FindThreshold[image, Method -> "Entropy"];

binImage = Binarize[image, t];
binImage2 = DeleteSmallComponents[binImage, 8];

newImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage2];

ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]]

{{40.3237, 638.086}, {730.063, 631.506}, {374.309, 32.0791}}

ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "Centroid"][[All, 2]]

{{40.522, 637.764}, {729.906, 631.188}, {374.087, 32.2067}}

ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "Medoid"][[All, 2]]

{{40.5, 637.5}, {729.5, 631.5}, {374.5, 32.5}}
```

In the next step I called `ImageFeatureTrack` with the coordinates determined in the first image when using `IntensityCentroid`:

```
res = ImageFeatureTrack[
  images, {{40.08839050131926, 637.0655233069481}, {731.5865089398592,
     633.1207332490518}, {374.28972465774496, 29.967774188586418}}]
```

The output for the first 2 images is:

```
res[[1 ;; 2, All]]

{{{40.0884, 637.066}, {731.587, 633.121}, {374.29, 29.9678}}, 
{{40.2653, 638.126}, {730.079, 631.463}, {374.318, 32.0352}}}
```

As one can see the tracked coordinates in the second image differ from the coordinates determined with `ComponentMeasurements[newImage, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]]`.

**How does `ImageFeatureTrack` measures the objects' coordinates and which strategy is used to track them?**

> **How can I force `ImageFeatureTrack` to use the `IntensityCentroid` of objects for tracking?**

Comment: can you get out the data of `IntensityCentroid` at each frame and use list manipulation to proceed your data to get the desired result?

Comment: The question is about how `ImageFeatureTrack` functions and if it can be combined with `IntensityCentroid`.

Comment: I'm guessing that `ImageFeatureTrack` uses [`ImageKeypoints[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageKeypoints.html) under-the-hood, and thus uses SURF feature detection to determine a point - and may make use of the *strength* of this "blob" in tracking. But the underlying point detection algorithm seems inaccessible. The only options are `{Masking -> All, MaxFeatureDisplacement -> 15, 
 MaxFeatures -> Automatic, MaxIterations -> 20, Tolerance -> 0.03`}`

Comment: For accurate scientific subpixel measurements where it is necessary to define the method on how objects positions should be determined and tracked `ImageFeatureTrack` would be then useless.

Comment: @mrz well there is your answer.  The examples for `ImageFeatureTrack[]` do point towards it being used for feature tracking in videos, i.e. from a computer vision point-of-view, rather than for tracking particles in scientific image series. Take a look at things like http://icy.bioimageanalysis.org/plugin/Spot_Tracking or http://imagej.net/TrackMate

Comment: @blochwave: this is very helpfull ... **unfortunately it seems that nobody has ever written a object tracking software with mathematica** ... it exists under matlab, idl, python etc ...and as standalone software. Sad ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer from Wolfram Technical Support :**

In general `ImageFeatureTrack` automatically determines a set of feature points in the images to track. To track specific features we have the following options: either we can take a sequence of related images and find a common feature in them such as the `IntensityCentroid` or we can find the coordinates of some feature in the first image and then tracks the new coordinates of the same feature as it changes from one related image to the next.

In the first case one uses the function `ImageMeasurements[{image1, image2, ...,imageN}, property]` such as:

```
ImageMeasurements[{image1, image2, ...,imageN}, "IntensityCentroid"]
```

In the second case we use `ImageFeatureTrack` with `ImageMeasurements` to identify the coordinates of the required feature, such as:

```
ImageFeatureTrack[{image1, image2, ...,imageN}, ImageMeasurements[image1, property]]
```

In the particular case of `IntensityCentroid` we have:

```
ImageFeatureTrack[{image1, image2, ...,imageN}, 
   ImageMeasurements[image1, "IntensityCentroid"]]
```